# Is it possible to use UserProfileService to return all current Birthdays?

Tags: web-part, user-profile-service, client-object-model, user-profile-property

I am new to the UserProfileService web service, the url based service accessed through
`/_vti_bin/userprofileservice.asmx`

In reference to writing a JavaScript CSOM web part, I am wondering if it's possible to return a list of all Users who's Birthday property is today using this web service?

**additional resources**: [User-Profile-Properties-through-JSOM](https://www.nothingbutsharepoint.com/sites/eusp/Pages/SharePoint-2013-User-Profile-Properties-through-JSOM.aspx)
and http://spservices.codeplex.com

Comment: You can use  User-Profile-Properties-through-JSOM and get birthday with SPS-Birthday or http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/forums/sharepoint/en-US/98f90bed-6a59-4219-b89b-f6b65bfee95d/birthday-web-part-from-user-profile

Comment: What version of SharePoint?

Comment: I was given a SharePoint 2013 Site Collection.  Response headers show it is using the "15" folder.